# I have a question about GFCI circuits

Tags: electrical

I have a GFCI circuit in my kitchen.  I believe it is wired correctly but each time I test with a volt tester it trips.  Then nothing in the kitchen works.  can someone help me answer this question?

Comment: Do regular appliances work? How are you testing it?  It is normal for additional receptacles to be protected by a GFCI. However those should have a "GFCI protected" sticker. Homeowners often tear them off, thinking they are yet another moronic warning sticker.  Everytime I buy 4' fluorescent fixtures, the entire reflector is covered in warning stickers!

Comment: Are you pressing the GFCI testing button on your tester? The point of that button is to cause current imbalance so that a working GFCI receptacle trips. letting you know it's working.

Comment: How do you "test with a volt tester?"  What is it that "trips?"  And what is "this question?"

Comment: "can someone help me answer this question?" - Yes. See what I did there? Now, if you have another question ...

Answer (score 1):

Measuring with a volt meter may create enough of an imbalance to trip the GFCI depending on how you are making the measurement. From hot to ground may cause a trip but measuring hot to neutral it should not trip. Most modern GFCI'S are looking for the imbalance. The rest of the outlets being on the same circuit is the reason they are all de-energized.

Comment: In my garage I have a 10-year-old GFCI receptacle on a 20-A circuit. Connecting the ground and the neutral with a 6-inch piece of 12 AWG wire trips the receptacle.  Using my ancient VOM (Radio shack kit 30,000 ohm/V) to measure the gnd to neutral and gnd to hot voltages does not trip the receptacle.

Comment: Usually they trip at 6ma hot to neutral should never trip unless there is some leakage to ground.

Comment: As I understand it they trip if the *difference* in the current in the hot and neutral wires is ~6 mA or greater.  Somehow there must be a slight voltage difference between the neutral and the ground contacts in the receptacle and connecting them with a wire causes a current flow in the neutral ground loop sufficient to trip the GFCI. I also tried this on a different circuit which is protected by a 15-A GFCI breaker--the breaker tripped. So connecting the ground and the neutral of a GFCI protected circuit trips the GFCI. NOTE: I am NOT recommending inserting a wire into the HOT side.

Comment: In both cases where I tripped a GFCI by connecting the neutral and the ground there were, or could have been, loads on the circuit. So connecting the ground and neutral would have shunted some of the current through the ground and hence caused an imbalance which tripped the breaker.

Comment: The imbalance the modern GFCI circuitry is looking for is current not voltage if there is an imbalance on hot and neutral usually greater than 6ma the circuit will trip.

Comment: In the present discussion we are trying to determine why the OP's GFCI receptacle is tripping when he connects wires to the load terminals of the GFCI receptacle. He says he thinks that wires connected to the load terminals of the GFCI go to exactly one other receptacle. I have suggested that the gnd and neutral are shorted in the cable or in the other receptacle. What do you think of this suggestion of mine?

Comment: A short of the ground to neutral after the device can cause enough of an imballance to trip the circuit.